# Scaner operates but gives error

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, scanner, sane

I've done a hard drive backup and reinstalled my OS (Linux Mint 20.2).

Now `simple-scan` refuses to be simple. It runs. Detects the scanner, The scanner scans when I click "scan". But when the scanner has finished I get the following [Unable to start scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sWyU.png) Error.

But if I `sudo simple-scan`. Everything works fine. I'm guessing this is a permissions problem, but so far I'm stuck?

Any help would be fabulous.

Comment: Start it from terminal (as ordinary user) and check for permissions errors

Comment: I ran if from a terminal as you suggested and it did the same thing as from the menu.
I've done some searching and I'm not sure how to work out the permissions thing?